# Как разбить данную строчку в массив в php?

Tags: php, массивы, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно разбить данную строку:

```
[[1000,1500,5000,10000,19000,6000],[5,20,30,40,50,60]]
```

в два массива? Читал, что можно с помощью регулярного выражения, но с регулярками у меня не очень.

Comment: скорее json_decode ))

Comment: @sepgg да конечно :D опечатался

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это типичная JSON строка. Примените к ней функцию `json_decode()`

```
$str = '[[1000,1500,5000,10000,19000,6000],[5,20,30,40,50,60]]';
$arr = json_decode($str, false, 3);
if (!$arr)
  die(json_last_error_msg());
var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Регулярки здесь не нужны. Просто преобразовываем JSON-строку в массив:

```
$json_string = '[[1000,1500,5000,10000,19000,6000], [5,20,30,40,50,60]]';
$arr = json_decode($json_string);
```